# How to "cut" "less-than" sign from "diff" output?

Tags: bash, grep, diff

How can I cut last "<" ?
Here is my output :

```
#20 17 03 45 * root bash /media/data/loop.sh <
```

and this is my command

```
diff filecron filecrontmp | grep "<" | head -n 1
```

I just want `#20 17 03 45 * root bash /media/data/loop.sh` for output.
What command should I pipe again? I've try with `xargs` but nothing happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the below sed command,

```
$ echo '#20 17 03 45 * root bash /media/data/loop.sh <' | sed 's/ [^ ]*$//'
#20 17 03 45 * root bash /media/data/loop.sh
```

It would remove the last space and the following characters. So your command would be,

```
diff filecron filecrontmp | grep "<" | head -n 1 | sed 's/ [^ ]*$//'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using BASH string manipulations:

```
s='#20 17 03 45 * root bash /media/data/loop.sh <'
echo "${s%<*}"
#20 17 03 45 * root bash /media/data/loop.sh
```